# Chrome without the chrome?

Tags: javascript, desktop-application

I'm developing a desktop application which is completely written in javascript + web services. I'd like to host it in a chromeless web browser. So basically just a window. I don't want the URL bar, I don't want the big blue bar, etc. I just want a window. Without anything. (although I may want an "x" to close it).

I'm not sure if chrome supports this, but I'm looking for a webkit based browser that can do this. (I looked into C#/Awesomium but I'd rather have a regular mainstream browser rather than updating pesky DLLs all the time to support new features)

Comment: yes, but i don't want it maximized necessarily...

Comment: I think the best way to do that, is embedding a browser in a C# application.

Comment: I think that you can use webkit core directly. For instance, qt has widget for this: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qtwebkit.html

Answer (score 7):

If you are working in Windows and you have Chrome installed you can create a shortcut with the following Target:

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --app=http://google.com`

And Start In:

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application`

This will give you what you want.

To do this on any web page in Chrome go to the wrench --> tools --> Create application shortcuts, here you can add it to Desktop / Start Menu / Pin to Taskbar

Comment: Note that the wrench is no longer the wrench but is the hamburger icon.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a pretty simple solution to this if you have your app installed as a web app in Chrome. On Chrome's new tab page (in the app section), right click the app and simply pick **Open as Window** instead of **Open as Regular Tab**. This gives you a window that features only the web page inside of regular OS window decorations, naturally.

Now, as far as I know, this selection can't be controlled by the developer, which makes sense, I guess. But if you want Chrome without the chrome (that's a really nice catchphrase or w/e btw), this is probably the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use command line switches for Chrome / Chromium:

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

check out `--kiosk`, `--enable-fixed-layout`, and `--window-size`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the kiosk mode of google-chrome.

1. Create a shortcut of your web application
2. go to its properties
3. in the target field append this flag --kiosk
4. save
5. open your shortcut